# Polymer dart and styling

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to find some information about styling a polymer dart element without much success. None of the info on Stackoverflow seems to work. Does anyone knows of some current information about styling polymer element?

I have seen where the .. tags can be used. I have tried it but with no success. Can an element be styled using a link to a .css file. I have also tried this without much success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small blog post about styling custom elements in Dart. Maybe this helps:

http://www.roberthartung.de/dartpolymer-styling-elements/

Regards
Robert

Comment: Thanks Robert! It worked! I actually am stylying my application now. I like the usage of the website styling applied to the custom elements. Appreciate the help. My major mistake was putting my styles in the :host { } selector. Also I was using @host instead of :host...

Comment: Yes, you can use that as well of course :-) I might add the :host-part to my post as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reference documentation I use:

- http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html
- http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html